# Improve on insert into table from date range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I had two table, one is List table and here is the data type of table

```
create table List(
   CustNo Int,
   NoOverDue money,
   OverDue1 money,
   OverDue2 money,
   OverDue3 money,
   OverDue4 money
)
```

and a table call tablecost

```
create table tablecost(
    custno int,
    cost money,
    DueDate datetime,
    ListDate datetime
)
```

My Table there had too many data so i create few data column for you to solve my question faster.

```
insert into tablecost values (1,100,'20130812','20130712')
insert into tablecost values (2,100,'20130612','20130712')
insert into tablecost values (3,100,'20130512','20130712') 
insert into tablecost values (4,100,'20130412','20130712') 
insert into tablecost values (5,100,'20130312','20130712') 
insert into tablecost values (6,100,'20130112','20130712')
```

and the purpose is insert into my `List` table
that:

if my duedate is not over, it will insert into nooverdue.

if overdue between 1 to 30 days,  it will insert into overdue1.

if overdue between 31 to 60 days,  it will insert into overdue2.

if overdue between 61 to 90 days,  it will insert into overdue3.

if overdue between 91 to 120 days,  it will insert into overdue4.

this is what i try on the query and it work fine:

```
insert into List (CustNo, NoOverDue)
select CustNo,Cost from TableCost
where  DueDate > GetDate() 
and convert(varchar(8),ListDate,112) between '20130711' and '20130713'

insert into List (CustNo, OverDue1)
select CustNo,Cost from TableCost
where  DueDate between DateAdd(Day,-30,GetDate()) and DateAdd(Day,-1,GetDate()) 
and convert(varchar(8),ListDate,112) between '20130711' and '20130713'

insert into List (CustNo, OverDue2)
select CustNo,Cost from TableCost
where  DueDate between DateAdd(Day,-60,GetDate()) and DateAdd(Day,-31,GetDate())
and convert(varchar(8),ListDate,112) between '20130711' and '20130713'

insert into List (CustNo, OverDue3)
select CustNo,Cost from TableCost
where  DueDate between DateAdd(Day,-90,GetDate()) and DateAdd(Day,-61,GetDate()) 
and convert(varchar(8),ListDate,112) between '20130711' and '20130713'

insert into List (CustNo, OverDue4)
select CustNo,Cost from TableCost
where  DueDate between DateAdd(Day,-120,GetDate()) and DateAdd(Day,-91,GetDate()) 
and convert(varchar(8),ListDate,112) between '20130711' and '20130713'
```

here my question, is there any posibility way to shorten or improve the query code?
it seem to long to make this query insert into this table only

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a logical difference between the different `overdue` columns. That suggests that they ought to be a single column. Perhaps what you need are `CustNo, DueAmount,OverdueStatus` (where `DueAmount` receives the current values you're storing in these columns and `OverdueStatus` is some kind of indicator of "not" or 1-4)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever problem is i need generate this kind of report and require doing some + and - value on specific column

Comment: How you display data is far removed from how you ought to be storing it. For *output* purposes, you can perform a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: I just HAVE to quote Damien: too often data storage is based on output needs. Store data as per it's logical, real-life schema. Then perform output queries/views/reports per your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with comments that you better separate storage and presentation needs for your data. But if you still need to achieve your current goal a possible solution might be

```sql
INSERT INTO List (CustNo, NoOverDue, OverDue1, OverDue2, OverDue3, OverDue4)
SELECT CustNo
      ,CASE WHEN ddiff < 1 THEN Cost END NoOverDue
      ,CASE WHEN ddiff BETWEEN  1 AND  30 THEN Cost END OverDue1
      ,CASE WHEN ddiff BETWEEN 31 AND  60 THEN Cost END OverDue2
      ,CASE WHEN ddiff BETWEEN 61 AND  90 THEN Cost END OverDue3
      ,CASE WHEN ddiff BETWEEN 91 AND 120 THEN Cost END OverDue4
  FROM 
(
  SELECT t.*, DATEDIFF(DAY, duedate, GETDATE()) ddiff
    FROM TableCost t
   WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ListDate, 112) BETWEEN '20130711' AND '20130713'
     AND DATEDIFF(DAY, duedate, GETDATE()) <= 120
) q
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65865/1)** demo

Comment: thank it really work same solution as before and it shorten a lot